# Is there a name for the involution on Laurent polynomials?

Tags: notation, polynomials, terminology

This is a simple terminology question: I want to know if the involution $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ on Laurent polynomials (over some ring, I happen to be working over $\mathbb{Z}$ but that's not important) has a special name.

My motivation is perhaps a little unusual for this site.  I'm doing some computations that involve manipulating Laurent polynomials and, being a lazy sort of fellow, I'm letting the computer do it.  Being extra lazy, I don't particularly want to learn a new programming language to do this so I'm using Perl as it's the only one that I know.  However, there my laziness stops as whilst there's a Perl module for ordinary polynomials there isn't one for Laurent polynomials.  Still, it wasn't hard to adapt it to Laurent polynomials so I did and the program is chugging away churning out these computations to its heart's content.  In writing the methods (meaning, things you can do to a Laurent polynomial), most already have obvious names (add, subtract - actually called `sub_`, mul(tiplication), and so forth) but I don't know one for the obvious involution $z \mapsto z^{-1}$.  `inv` sounds a little to easy to mistake for `inverse`.

So, is there a name for this?  If not, would anyone like to suggest one (preferably with an unambiguous shortening - I've already gotten fed up of typing `monomial` every time)?

Comment: Reverse? It's just reading the coefficients backwards.

Comment: I call it conjugation, since when you specialize $z$ to a unit complex number that's what it is and this is a pretty common thing to do.  Most texts/papers I've read just say "ring with involution" in these situations. 

Comment: I would call it the bar involution.

Comment: By the way, I wiki-hammered.

Comment: Ryan: but it's not complex conjugation: $z^{-1}$ and $\overline{z}$ are two different things, aren't they?  Ben: I was anticipating a few votes-to-close, but the wiki-hammer?  I realise that my "would anyone like to suggest one" sounds a bit like it should be CW, but I was hoping that there would be a single, definite answer and would expect to wait to see if there were before wikifying.

Comment: They're the same when $z$ is a *unit* complex number.  So I see no harm in calling it conjugation.   I think I've seen this convention in some knot theory texts.  It's also advantageous since it allows for notational sloppiness $z^{-1} = \overline{z}^1$.  When you're computing Alexander polynomials and if you have sloppy handwriting, this is a major advantage. 

Comment: Ryan: my main issue with conjugation is that if the coefficient ring happens to be $\mathbb{C}$ then I would expect conjugation to act on the coefficients as well.

Comment: Oops! When Ben Webster said that he "wiki-hammered" I thought he
meant "hammered widipedia for an answer (see my answer below). I guess he meant he made this question communitiy wiki--a good call, IMO.

Comment: I don't much care either way, but I don't think that this is the type of question that should be wiki-hammered.

Comment: In Milnor's "Reidemeister Torsion" just before Lemma 4 it's called conjugation, for example. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it the antipode.  If your base ring is commutative, then the Laurent polynomials are the coordinate ring of the multiplicative group, and the antipode gives you the inversion on the group scheme.

Comment: I'm going for "antipode".  "Bar" is too close to conjugation for my liking.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer to the original question is that there is no special name for the involution (otherwise it would have turned up by now).   My first encounter with it was in the 1979 Kazhdan-Lusztig paper on Hecke algebras, where they use a
bar notation and combine this involution on Laurent polynomials with the inversion in a given Coxeter group to get an action on the Hecke algebra of that Coxeter group.   The bar notation makes it unnecessary to invent a name for the
involution on Laurent polynomials, but "bar involution" will certainly do.

By the way, a ring of Laurent polynomials (say over $\mathbb{Z}$) provides a nice nontrivial example for a graduate algebra course, even though it rarely if ever occurs in textbooks.    It's natural to ask what are the prime ideals and factor rings, etc.  Most often the examples of commutative rings which students see are too boring and predictable to motivate the ideal machinery.

Comment: Nice example of an interesting ring!

Answer (score 4):

I'm with David here.  It's "the bar involution," a very hard involution to write the symbol for alone.

Comment: But `bar` is a perfectly good command in a Perl script!

Comment: Theo: fits very well with `foo`!

Answer (score 0):

"Argument involution"? I have never heard a name for the map, and I'm sure
I would use "the $z\leftrightarrow z^{-1}$ map" as the name, in a paper.

Answer (score -2):

Well, to offer a somewhat garbled paraphrase T.S. "Old Possum" Elliot
(see for example, http://www.americanpoems.com/poets/tseliot/5536):

**You may think at first I'm as mad as a hatter**

**But The Naming of Things is a difficult matter,**

**It isn't just one of your holiday games!**

Having so established my credentials in this matter, I present the following:

Think of the map $z \to z^{-1}$ as swapping charts on the Riemann sphere. (I'm OK
with here, right? I mean, I haven't looked carefully at this stuff in quite awhile.)
Think of the $z$-coordinate as corresponding to the North Pole. Then the $z^{-1}$- coordinate goes with the South Pole.

Now, like Ben Webster, I gots out my lil' ol' wiki hammer, yes I did, but just
gave the great wiki mountain a tiny tap: what broke off was: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Star.

The North Star is Polaris; the South Star is one *Sigma Octantis*.

Therefore, reminiscent, of the notion that the map $z \to z^{-1}$ is somewhat of
a swap twixt north and south, how about calling your involution something based
on *Sigma Octantis*?

List:

**SigmaOctantisInvolution----way to long to type**

**SigOct or sigoct----shorter, not too long, you'll not likely forget it**

gee, what about

$\Sigma$ **or perhaps** $\sigma$ **----hard to do on a keyboard; BUT there is**

**"sigma or perhaps just "sig"---beginning to look like "real math"!**

Ah ha! Abara K'Dabara--I create as I speak!  From now on, I call the involution $z \to z^{-1}$
on the algebra of Laurent polynomials $\sigma$.  You could call it *sig* for short; if
that's a reserved word in Perl use a variant like *sigoct* etc. Or perhaps even
better, for a function in a computer language, *siginv*--for the *sigma involution*,
though I'd probably just go with *sig* if I could.

BTW, this question inspired one of my own: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48994/humorous-curious-unusual-names-for-mathematical-entities

**HAPPY HOLIDAYS LADIES AND GENTLEMEN OF MO--HO! HO! HO!**

Comment: @Ben Webster--will, if not $\sigma$, maybe $\beta$--for "bar" involution.

Comment: BTW, my "inspired question" was promptly closed.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: so what name *did* you finally decide on?

Comment: Second thoughts--the involution $z \to z^{-1}$ is somewhat peculiar
to Laurent polynomials and series; the ordinary "bar" symbol can be
confused with (complex) conjugation; so maybe in the light of 
Scott Carnahan's answer this involution should be called $\alpha$
(for antipode) or perhaps $\lambda$-for Laurent.